# Array to string conversion laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

i need to get the values without string in array. this will be name of fields :

```
 static function showCust(){
   $table = DB::table("dummy_db.customer")->select("*")->paginate(10);
   $getFieldName = ["CUST_NAME", "CUST_CITY"];

   foreach($table as $items){
        $a[] = $items->$getFieldName[0];
   }
   dd($a);
}
```

but the results :

`ErrorException
Array to string conversion.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1: call object property by element of array

The error msg occurs because `$getFieldName` as a variable, object call the variable without `[0]`, you need to wrap `$getFieldName[0]` with brace:

```php
$items->{$getFieldName[0]};
```

#### Problem 2: Get collection from paginator:

You are applying `paginate` to query-builder, the result will be `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` object.

If you want to get the customer objects inside. You can use `getCollection()` method to `$table`:

```php
   foreach($table->getCollection() as $items){
        $a[] = $items->${getFieldName[0]};
   }
```

Comment: Solved,  its running $items->${getFieldName[0]}; Thank You Tsaitoga.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve only the list of `CUST_CITY` with the key `CUST_NAME` you can use the `pluck()` method:

```
$array = DB::table("dummy_db.customer")
    ->take(10)
    ->pluck('CUST_CITY','CUST_NAME');
```